# Auto-open does not work for people who have not signed in in browser

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-app

I want to share a document online by a URL with some colleagues. When they click the URL and view the document online, I want a task-pane add-in to be automatically opened.

I used [Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin) to create such a file with Script Lab auto-opened, then I put the file (view-only) on my OneDrive:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmAcI5jpNEmng1NhS0xbIMcUnUNZ

However, our tests show that, for people who have not signed in with Microsoft Account in their browser, the auto-open does NOT work, though they can view the document.

Is this behavior expected, given that people may not stay signed in all the time?

PS: note that if people download the document, they don't need to sign in to enable auto-open in Excel desktop.

Comment: I'm making some inquiries internally in Microsoft. I'll let you know if I learn anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug. Until it is fixed, users will have to be logged in when they open a document on OneDrive in order for the autoopen feature to work. Sorry for the bad news, but it is on Microsoft's radar and we know it is important.

Comment: OK... thank you for letting me know. I also notice that, in browser, when a signed-in user closes the document without clicking on `Trust this add-in` or `See Details`, next time when he opens the document, auto-open may or may not work. I will do more tests tomorrow.

Comment: Hello Rick, I would like to know if you have fixed the bug. My tests show that the bug (e.g., users will have to be logged in when they open a document on OneDrive in order for the autoopen feature to work) still exists.

Comment: Sorry. Still not fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the update... Do you have any idea about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137100/cannot-share-an-autoopen-tagged-document-in-read-only-mode)?