# Cannot share an autoopen-tagged document in read-only mode

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, onedrive, excel-online

I have an Excel file in my OneDrive, I want to create a URL link such that:

1) when my colleagues open the URL in a browser, it could open the file in Excel Online in the **read-only mode**,

2) and the task-pane of Script Lab is auto-opened.

I have followed [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin) to tag my document, then uploaded it to OneDrive. Then, I used `Share` to share this document in OneDrive as follows. Note that I well set "Anyone with the link can view"

[image]

Here is the link: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmAcI5jpNEmng2vYPFkfDRVMDFCP?e=F1I824

My tests showed that for an authenticated user, the link does trigger the auto-open of the task-pane of ScriptLab. Though, for a non-authenticated user, the link does NOT trigger the auto-open, it is a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54935374/702977), which has not been fixed.

However, my tests showed that a non-authenticated user can not edit the file (which is expected), **whereas another authenticated user can well edit the file, this is not what the read-only mode is supposed to do**.

Additionally, my tests showed that a non-autoopen-tagged file does not have this problem; the read-only mode works well.

Does anyone know what is happening here, is it a bug?

Is there any other way to share a document (by Microsoft Graph?) such that it could 1) trigger autoopen and 2) be read-only?